# Working with ASP.Net Web Forms Views

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, webforms

I have this code in my view page

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink_TruckList" runat="server" 
     Text="Truck List" NavigateUrl="~/View/Trucklist.aspx" 
     Font-Underline="false"></asp:HyperLink>
```

How to add -

```
class="col-sm-4" 
style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; color: black; height: 40px; padding-top: 8px; background: #E8D73E">
```

and

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
```

on it?

Answer (score 2):

Server Control **CssClass** and **Style** property are equivalent to HTML **class** and **style** attribute respectively.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink_TruckList" runat="server" Text="Truck List" NavigateUrl="~/View/Trucklist.aspx" Font-Underline="false" CssClass="col-sm-4" Style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; color: black; height: 40px; padding-top: 8px; background: #E8D73E">
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly add this in your css file

```
.need
{
text-align: center; font-size: 18px; color: black; 
height: 40px; padding-top: 8px; background: #E8D73E;
}
```

and then simply write this code

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink_TruckList" runat="server" 
 Text="Truck List" NavigateUrl="~/View/Trucklist.aspx" CssClass="col-sm-4 need"
 Font-Underline="false">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> 
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append styles programmatically

```
hyperlink_TruckList.Style.Add("class", "col-sm-4");
hyperlink_TruckList.Style.Add("style", "text-align: center; font-size: 18px; color: black; height: 40px; padding-top: 8px; background: #E8D73E");
```